# track user activity in the website - google analytics

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, google-analytics

I have to develop a website (using open cms joomla) which will contain various features like chatting, forums, blogs...And I would like to monitor how much logged in user is spending on different features (chatting,...). Can I do this with google analytics or I have to develop my  solution to do this.

Any help is appreciated. thanks !

Comment: You can try [Lucky Orange](http://www.luckyorange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Google has [event tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) which will quite likely suite your needs.